# Am I supposed to pay for parking when the parking meter is buried under the snow (USA)?

Tags: usa, regulations, driving

I am travelling by car in the USA (Boston, Massachusetts). The weather is currently pretty snowy. Am I supposed to pay for parking when the parking meter is buried under the snow?

E.g.:

[image]

Comment: Are the spaces visible?

Comment: @GayotFow Parking spaces are sometime visible.

Comment: If the spaces are visible, then you should make a REASONABLE ATTEMPT to pay. Define 'reasonable' and 'attempt' in any way that sounds convincing. Take a picture with your mobile, whatever...

Comment: @GayotFow "REASONABLE ATTEMPT" for me means bringing my own shovel and dig the meter out ;)

Comment: @MeNoTalk, I used to drive a taxi in Boston and came to appreciate their 'reasonable man' doctrine, which works quite well in local courts there.  See http://www.personaldefensenetwork.com/the-reasonable-man-doctrine/

Comment: @GayotFow - on behalf of Britain, you're welcome ;) (Also, you still owe us some tea) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaughan_v_Menlove

Comment: How do you proceed if you cannot see any indication that payment is required?

Comment: @Gusdor Parking restrictions are indicated by signs as well as the meters themselves, and sometimes also by road striping and curb painting (hence *"The white zone is for immediate loading and unloading of passengers only"*). Even after historic snows, the signs are rarely covered for long. Of course, even without snow, you still have to deal with [confusing and contradictory](http://laist.com/2014/06/20/photos_los_angeles_most_ridiculous.php#photo-1) signs in most cities.

Comment: I would be amazed if you can even find a space. Helpful hint: if you move a lawn chair or other improvised obstruction from a space, do not expect your car to be drivable when you return.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The answer depends on the municipality. In the case of Boston, the short answer is **yes**:

> [Parking meters remain in effect](http://www.cityofboston.gov/snow/parking/)

during snow emergencies.

**But**, while parking enforcement will be active in the city, their focus will be towing cars parked on "snow emergency arteries" (i.e. major thoroughfares which receive priority attention for snow abatement for use by snow removal equipment and emergency vehicles) and on other violations that could exacerbate problems in a major snow event, like parking in front of a fire hydrant.

And as noted in a recent public radio story, city officials [“don’t want anyone to fall and hurt themselves”](http://www.wbur.org/2015/01/29/parking-meters-snow) trying to get to a meter.

> If you do get a ticket for not paying and you feel you couldn’t get to the meter, [Boston Transportation Department spokeswoman Tracey] Ganiatsos advises that you take a picture of the snow in front of the meter, if that’s the case, and appeal the ticket.…
>
> But, whether or not a meter is accessible for payment, the city will ticket drivers who are parked longer than the meter time limit — which is two hours in most parts of the city — Ganiatsos said.

See www.cityofboston.gov/snow for an overview of all the city's snow policies and procedures, but remember neighboring municipalities like Cambridge or Brookline have their own, and may not apply the same standards that Boston does.

Comment: A city law about "what to do when the parking machine is under snow" counts as of the stranger things I've heard of.

Comment: @yo' It's not in places where being buried under snow is something that has happened before and has a reasonable chance of happening again.

Comment: @DanNeely I know. It seems that I forgot to tag the comment as _/sarcasm_, sorry for that :D